# Replacing Visible cells in a column with data from other column

Tags: excel, vba

Here's my issue, I am filtering column S by type "Large", after that, I go to the visible cells in column T and replace it with the data in column V. The issue is that the data fluctuates so I can't just have my macro replace all of column T with column V.

I have code for the filtering and visible rows, but I do not know how to finish the macro code so it replaces the visible cells in column T with the visible cells in column V. Column V also varies so T4 must be replaced with V4 and then T27 must be replaced with V27 ETC... those are arbitrary #'s the visible cells can switch each week.

```
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:= _
    "Large"

    Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, LstRw As Long

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
    With sh
    LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & LstRw).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

What would my best code look like to satisfy the need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub testFilterReplaceVisCells()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, rngT As Range
  Dim LstRw As Long, rngArea As Range, cel As Range
  
  Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
  sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter field:=19, Criteria1:="Large"
  LstRw = sh.cells(rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
        
  Set rngT = sh.Range("T2:T" & LstRw).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    For Each rngArea In rngT.Areas
        For Each cel In rngArea.cells
            cel.value = sh.cells(cel.row, "V").value
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: So that replaced the data in visible column V with the data in column T, which is just vice versa of the intended replacing visible data in column T with the visible data in column V

Comment: Ups... I misunderstood the question. I will adapt it in a minute... **Adapted**.

Comment: Yep all fixed now. Thanks for helping me out that's awesome!

Comment: I have a quick follow up Q if you don't mind. So earlier in my code I already had entered ' Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, LstRw As Long ' This causes me to get the compile error. Without editing your code in the answer, what should I remove from it so I don't get the error and the code still works? (I don't know much about troubleshooting code)

Comment: @LittleAuditorium: No problem to assist you. But I did not exactly understood where is the problem... All what you say about variables declarations is already in my code. Do you have problems trying the above code? If yes, do you test it as it is? If you tried modifying it, please edit your question, post the modified code and explain what error and on which line. And Tag me here, please.

Comment: Sorry I was actually able to figure it out. I just took out the variables I already defined in my previous comment. Now the full code flows perfectly incorporated into my previous code. Thanks again for all your help